# javascript - find the div with the longest width in the webpage

Tags: javascript

How can I find the longest div in a webpage?

I mean the div that has the longest width.

I would use pure javascript, is there some way to do it?

Comment: so what have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var largestDivIndex = null;
var allDivs = document.getElementsByTagName('div');

for (var i = 0 ; i < allDivs.length ; i++) {
  if (largestDivIndex === null 
     || (allDivs[largestDivIndex].offsetWidth < allDivs[i].offsetWidth)
  ) { 
    largestDivIndex = i;
  }
};

console.log(largestDivIndex, allDivs[largestDivIndex]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can loop over all `DIV`s on the page and compare their widths:

```
function getWidestDiv() {
    var divs = document.getElementsByTagName("div");
    var widestElement = divs[0];
    for(var i = 0; i < divs.length; i++) {
        if (divs[i].clientWidth > widestElement.clientWidth) {
            widestElement = divs[i];
        }
    }
    return widestElement;
}
```